# Gradle Lombok constructor annotation fail

Tags: java, android, gradle, lombok

I'm trying to use Lombok in Android Studio with no luck. I'm working on a git project and since the project decided to use Lombok I could not build it. The build fails on `compileDevelopmentDebugJava` task and the error message says:

```
Error:A default public constructor with no argument must be declared if a custom constructor is declared.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDevelopmentDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

It doesn't matter if I build in Android Studio or CMD, the error stays the same.

Versions used:

- Android Studio 1.2 beta 3
- Gradle 2.3.9
- Lombok 1.12
- Java JDK 1.7

Comment: Do you have a public no-arg constructor for the classes using Lombok?

Comment: No. All the constructors are generated from the annotations. The problem is on my computer, it builds on the build server.